# C# Drawing multiple charts in real time in a separate thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms, charts, real-time

I have a acquistion device that reads data and adds it to the buffer. This is done in a separate thread. Once this data is dequeued, I set up a delegate that raise the event OnDataRead().

In my signal monitor, when the event is received I want to plot the data in multiple charts (16 in total). Since I have 16 charts, instead of updating the charts every time new data is received, I add them in a buffer for the data and the timestamps. The charts are updated in a separate thread every 100ms by reading the data stored in the buffer and the timestamps. However, when I plot the data, some charts stop adding data and in all charts, lot of values are not displayed. Is this a bad approach? What would be a better approach or what should I change to make it work?

I have 256samples/second*16channels.

This is what I get
[image: signal monitor (16 channels)]

This is what I would expect but for all 16 channels

[image]

```
 public void OnDataRead(object source, DataEventArgs e)
    {
         if ((e.rawData.Length > 0) && (!_shouldStop))
            {
                for (int sampleIdx = 0; sampleIdx < e.rawData.Length; sampleIdx++)
                {
                    lock (_bufferRawData)
                        // Append data
                        _bufferRawData.Add(e.rawData[sampleIdx]);

                    lock (_bufferXValues)
                        _bufferXValues.Add(DateTime.Now);

                }
    }

 private void AddDataThreadLoop()
        {
            while (!_shouldStop)
            {
                chChannels[1].Invoke(addDataDel);

                Thread.Sleep(100); //sleeps for 100ms
            }
        }

 private void AddData()
        {

            // Copy data stored in lists to arrays
            if (_bufferRawData.Count > 0)
            {
                float[] rawData;
                lock (_bufferRawData)
                {
                    rawData = _bufferRawData.ToArray();
                    _bufferRawData.Clear();
                }
                DateTime[] xValues;
                lock (_bufferXValues)
                {
                    xValues = _bufferXValues.ToArray();
                    _bufferXValues.Clear();
                }

                // Add new data points for the selected channel chart
                int channelIdx = 0; 

                for (int sampleIdx = 0; sampleIdx < rawData.Length -1; sampleIdx++)
                {
                    // Calculate the channel where the smaple corersponds
                    channelIdx = sampleIdx % (_numChannels + 1);

                   foreach (Series ptSeries in chChannels[channelIdx].Series)
                            // Add new datapoint to the corresponding chart (x, y, chartIndex, seriesIndex)
                            AddNewPoint(xValues[sampleIdx], rawData[sampleIdx], channelIdx, ptSeries);

                }
            }
        }

public void AddNewPoint(DateTime timeStamp, float yValue, int chartIDx, System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series ptSeries)
    {

        //Add datapoint
        ptSeries.Points.AddXY(timeStamp.ToOADate(), yValue);

        // Remove old datapoints if needed
        double removeBefore = timeStamp.AddSeconds((double)(8) * (-1)).ToOADate();
        while (ptSeries.Points[0].XValue < removeBefore)
        {
            ptSeries.Points.RemoveAt(0);
        }

        // Modify minimum and maximum for new samples
        chChannels[chartIDx].ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = ptSeries.Points[0].XValue;
        chChannels[chartIDx].ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = DateTime.FromOADate(ptSeries.Points[0].XValue).AddSeconds(10).ToOADate();
        chChannels[chartIDx].ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = _yMax;
        chChannels[chartIDx].ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = -_yMax;

        chChannels[chartIDx].Invalidate();
    }

private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //Create thread
     //define a thread to add values into chart
     ThreadStart addDataThreadObj = new ThreadStart(AddDataThreadLoop);
     addDataRunner = new Thread(addDataThreadObj);
     addDataDel += new AddDataDelegate(AddData);

     //Start thread
     addDataRunner.Start();
    }
```

**EDIT1:**
chChanels is a list of charts where each element correspond to one of the charts.
     public List chChannels;

**EDIT2**
After changing the lock for this, all charts are updated. However lot of samples for each chart are still not updated.

```
 lock (_bufferRawData) {
        for (int sampleIdx = 0; sampleIdx < e.rawData.Length; sampleIdx++)
        {
           // Append data
           _bufferRawData.Add(e.rawData[sampleIdx]);
           _bufferXValues.Add(DateTime.Now);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: What is `chChannels`? I'm afraid it's difficult to get very far with any attempt to help you unless you provide an example that can actually be compiled and tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two problems in the code:

1) Using locks in a non-efficient way. I replaced the two single locks for a common lock. I also lock it for all iterations instead of do it for every single iteration, as pointed out in one of the answers. This is how it should be

```
 lock (_bufferRawData) {
        for (int sampleIdx = 0; sampleIdx < e.rawData.Length; sampleIdx++)
        {
           // Append data
           _bufferRawData.Add(e.rawData[sampleIdx]);
           _bufferXValues.Add(DateTime.Now);
        }
    }
```

2) The timestamps that I was generating didn't correspond of the timestamps when the data was collected. Hence, several Y samples have the same or similar timestamps.

One solution is to generate the exact timestamp for every sample. That should be done when the samples are acquired. However, since the frequency rate is 256Hz, that correspond to 1 sample every 4ms. The precision of DateTime.Now is around 15ms, which makes this approach not suitable for a frequency rate of 256Hz. However, that will be a good approach for lower frequency rates.

The correct approach is to determine the X-axis value for the graph when the data is plotted. Since the frequency is fixed at 256Hz, it is easy to know the X values of the Y samples.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say if these are your only issues but at a minimum this stands out to me:

1. You are using two separate locks for the timestamps and the raw data buffers. This means that it is possible for the buffers to not represent the same series of data. You'll probably want to use a single lock to access both buffers:

   ```
   lock (_bufferRawData) {
       // Append data
       _bufferRawData.Add(e.rawData[sampleIdx]);
       _bufferXValues.Add(DateTime.Now);
   }
   ```

In fact, I would also recommend moving the locking out of the for-loop. It's super inefficient to lock on each iteration:

```
    lock (_bufferRawData) {
        for (int sampleIdx = 0; sampleIdx < e.rawData.Length; sampleIdx++)
        {
           // Append data
           _bufferRawData.Add(e.rawData[sampleIdx]);
           _bufferXValues.Add(DateTime.Now);
        }
    }
```

2. The other thing that you're doing that could be improved (but doesn't necessarily explain why the data is looking strange) is you are sleeping in the thread that schedules the updates. You should probably replace that with a timer that fires periodically, and does the updates. And since you are invoking the updates on the UI thread, you could probably benefit from using a UI timer.

Comment: I changed the lock and now the charts are always updated. However, lots of values are still missed. Could it be related to the DateTime.Now? Or perhaphs the sleep as you suggested.

Comment: @nabrugir - yes, it is highly likely that it is the DateTime.Now that is causing the trouble. DateTime.Now is just not reliable at that level. You may want to use a high-precision timer (see the System.Diagnostics.StopWatch) or perhaps even re-evaluate your time-stamping strategy all-together..